# Center image in div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` in a div (`class="top_image"`) and I want this image to be exactly in the middle of the div but nothing I try works...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should specify both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: Will the div and image dimensions always be known? Will the image be changing?

Answer (score 607, accepted):

**Every solution posted here assumes that you know the dimensions of your `img`, *which is not a common scenario.*** Also, planting the dimensions into the solution is painful.

Simply set:

```
/* for the img inside your div */
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

or

```
/* for the img inside your div */
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

That's all.

Note, that you'll also have to set an initial `min-width` for your outer `div`.

Comment: Perfect answer: This solution is also used in [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/image.less).

Comment: Note: This only works if the image's width is smaller than the parent div.

Comment: Is there a solution for an absolutely positioned image inside of of relatively positioned `<div>`?

Comment: does not work if image is larger than div

Comment: @BbIKTOP If your image is larger than its parent div, you can make the image smaller by applying width less than 100% to the image.

Answer (score 29):

text-align: center will only work for horizontal centering. For it to be in the complete center, vertical and horizontal you can do the following :

```
div
{
    position: relative;
}
div img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: [-50% of your image's width];
    margin-top: [-50% of your image's height];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `[-50% of your image's width/height]` :)

Comment: Yup, sorry, my bad. Typed a little fast. Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas if you don't know the size of the image beforehand..  I have to resize an image to be displayed in a container of fixed size, but the image could be wide or tall...

Comment: Sorry... figured it out... see solution in my answer..

Answer (score 12):

A very simple and elegant solution to this is provided by W3C. Simply use the margin:0 auto declaration as follows:

```
.top_image img { margin:0 auto; }
```

More information and [examples](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) from W3C.

Answer (score 9):

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_74so2YIdYpM/TEd09Hqrm6I/AAAAAAAAApY/rwGCm5_Tawg/s320/tall+copy.jpg" alt="tall image" />
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://www.5150studios.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/wide.jpg" alt="wide image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.outer
{
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.inner
{
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think its better to to do text-align center for div and let image take care of the height. Just specify a top and bottom padding for div to have space between image and div. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tv9mG/

Comment: Image is broken but works great

Answer (score 6):

I hope this would be helpful:

```
.top_image img{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: please tell what did u do here . explain.

Answer (score -6):

This took me way too long to figure out. I can't believe nobody has mentioned center tags.

Ex:

```
<center><img src = "yourimage.png"/></center>
```

and if you want to resize the image to a percentage:

```
<center><img src = "yourimage.png" width = "75%"/></center>
```

GG America

Comment: Center tags are now deprecated and are very frowned apon and is in the process of being dropped although it works in most browsers at the moment.

Comment: "GG America". Beautiful.

Comment: <center>  Not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
Defines centered text