# How to center images in div?

Tags: html, css, center, centering

How to make these images stay in center? Here are my css and html codes.

My html code:

```
<div id="logos">
  <div id="q">
    <img id="round" src="img/i1.jpg" />
    <img id="round" src="img/i1.jpg" />
    <img id="round" src="img/i1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
#logos {
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
}

#q{
 display: block;

 }
 #round {
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 5px;
 width: 150; 
 height: 150; 
 position: cetner;
}
```

Comment: `text-align:center;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - HTML: center Image in Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980531/css-html-center-image-in-div)

Comment: quick note: `id` should be unique per element. To use same identifier for more elements use `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align: center` on the parent...

```css
#q{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
 }

.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="logos">
    <div id="q">
        <img class="round" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <img class="round" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <img class="round" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, ID's must be unique. `rounded` should be a class not an ID.

Secondly, `position: center;` doesn't exist in CSS.

And finally, `width: 150` and `height: 150` must have a unit of measurement (probably `px`) though this will have no effect because the elements are `inline` - perhaps you meant `inline-block`?

Comment: Can you help me and explain how to add text bellow to each image?

Answer (score 1):

```
#image{
    text-align:center;
}

#image img{
    margin:0 auto;
}

<div class="image">
    <img src="path_to_your_image" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to #round css:

```
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 150px; /*units are needed */
height: 150px; /*units are needed */
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code

```
<div class="flex-align">
  <img class="round" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img class="round" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img class="round" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.flex-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```