# When my div is not getting horizontally centered?

Tags: css, html

Why is the image not centered here?

```css
#image {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
</div>
```

But it works perfect with a `<center>` tag.

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nn6s7c2j/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center image in div horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980531/center-image-in-div-horizontally)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div) and a multitude of similar answers found by searching SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could just use `flexbox`

```
#image {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You don't need the `90vh` or `90vw` but you do need to give the `height` and `width` some value. Whether it's in `px` or `%` is up to you.

Answer (score 4):

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nn6s7c2j/5/). Your `<div>` needs to be 100% in `width`, and the image has to be a block element; try this CSS:

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
}
#image img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will center `<img>` tags, as they have `display: inline-block;` by default. Only `display: block` elements can be centered using `margin: 0 auto;`.

Quick summary:

- Horizontally center `block` displayed elements using `margin: 0 auto;` on the element, to center relative to the parent element's width;
- Horizontally center `inline-block` displayed elements using `text-align: center;` on the parent element, to center relative to the parent element's width.

Answer (score 0):

Since an image is not a block element, it's enough just to add `text-align: center;` to its parent.

```
#image{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align:center;`

```css
#image{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  
     }
```

```html
<div id="image">
     <img src="https://scontent-kul.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s526x395/13934860_132991530474366_7559506120027031422_n.jpg?oh=54eb36c2f2b2383712a6dcf1da2cd638&oe=58212A26">
     </div>
```