# Align picture element in center of parent div keeps image aligned to left

Tags: css, html, image, alignment

I want to create a responsive hero image, but I can't seem to center my picture element in a parent div. I already checked these posts:

[Center image in div horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980531/center-image-in-div-horizontally)
[Center align image within div horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally)
[Center image element in parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428997/center-image-element-in-parent-div)

As suggested in these other posts, I tried playing with `margin: auto auto;`, with `position`, setting `min-width` to the parent div, but the image remains aligned to the far left.
[Here's an example](http://www.1001locaties.nl/beachclub-sunrise-315) of what I'm trying to achieve

And here's my code (I've also created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wuy44t9p/1/):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .profile-banner {
        display: block;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .profile-banner picture {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
    }   

</style>


<div id="CPHBigBanner_pnlCoverPhoto">   
    <section class="profile-banner lazy">
        <picture class="profile-herobanner lazy" data-was-processed="true">
            <source type="image/webp" class="lazy" data-srcset="http://www.1001locaties.nl/images/tmp/41747_965_Owl.webp" srcset="/images/objphotos/covers/41747_965_Owl.webp" data-was-processed="true">
            <img class="lazy loaded" data-src="http://www.1001locaties.nl/images/tmp/41747_965_Owl.png" alt="" src="/images/objphotos/covers/41747_965_Owl.png" data-was-processed="true">
        </picture>    
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the absolute positioning and you may need to give a width to the picture - at the moment it looks as if it may be as wide as it's container

Comment: Nice! That did the trick, however, the image width is not always known...is there a CSS solution that does not rely on providing the width?

Comment: You could try max-width:100% and it should restrain it to the max width of the image or the container depending on which is smallest

Comment: I removed the `width` attribute from `picture` and added `max-width: 100%;` but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments you need to remove the absolute positioning from the image but also add text-align center to the container:

```css
.profile-banner {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  text-align:center;
}

.profile-banner picture {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="CPHBigBanner_pnlCoverPhoto">
  <section class="profile-banner lazy">
    <picture class="profile-herobanner lazy" data-was-processed="true">
      <source type="image/webp" class="lazy" data-srcset="http://www.1001locaties.nl/images/tmp/41747_965_Owl.webp" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-was-processed="true">
      <img class="lazy loaded" data-src="http://www.1001locaties.nl/images/tmp/41747_965_Owl.png" alt="" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" data-was-processed="true">
    </picture>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that aligns the image correctly. However, the image is not responsive anymore...I tried setting `width:100%` on the `image` element, but that scales the images always to the full browser window width...how can I make the image responsive?

Comment: Give it a percentage other than 100%

Comment: I've just thought if you want it to be 100% up to the width of the image - and then it stops, you could use something like `width:100%; max-width:350px;` where the 350px is the original width of the image