# How to make image fit to div and centered at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css

If I want to fit a large image(with arbitrary aspect ratio) into a small div, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3029434/3043719), I just need to set the maximum width and height to 100%,

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

And if I need to further center the image, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16034913/3043719), we can set the margin to `auto`,

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But in this way, the image is only centered in horizontal. To have it vertically centered, I've tried following approaches but don't work.

```css
img {
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any one can help?

Comment: display flex or grid make this trivial

Comment: @Bravo With grid we can't control the size of the inner image.

Comment: would the image as a background work for your undefined requirements?

Comment: @Bravo that could be my last resort. I'd like to achieve it as a normal image.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div) work for you?

Comment: @vee let me try

Comment: Not sure if If follow. If the image is shrunk to fit the entire content of the div, how could it be centered if there is no padding outside of it?

Comment: @MaxVoisard If the width of the image hit the maximum width first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use display flex:

```css
.div {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.portrait {
  height: 80px;
  width: 30px;
}

.landscape {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
}

.square {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
Portrait Div
<div class="portrait div">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg" />
</div>
Landscape Div
<div class="landscape div">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg" />
</div>
Square Div
<div class="square div">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any equivalent solution in grid? It would be strange if only flex can do this.

Comment: yes, you can change `.div` class in the example above to `display: grid;
  grid-template: 100% / 100%;
  place-items: center;`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a small trick to use...

First, make sure the parent `div` is set to `position:relative;`

Then in the `img` add this values

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
```

This will automatically align the `img` in the middle of the parent `div`. You can delete all other values and use it like this

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on if the inline height and width of the parent div has an aspect ratio larger or smaller than the image, the image will center either horizontally or vertically. There is a little cheat with JavaScript, but looking at the CSS, this seems to be close to what you were initially attempting.

```js
$(".imgContainer").each(function() {
   const height = $(this).height() > $(this).children("img").eq(0).height() ? parseFloat($(this).height() * 0.99) + "px": "100%";
   $(this).css("line-height", height);
});
```

```css
.imgContainer {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.imgContainer img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgContainer" style="width: 435px; height: 320px">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WpTo.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imgContainer" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 435px; height: 260px">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WpTo.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imgContainer" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 435px; height: 289px">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WpTo.jpg">
</div>
```